# Cloning last row of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am cloning the last row of my table and I am using

```
$('#table tr:last').clone(true).appendTo('#table')
```

Clone last row and change the onchange part?

```
<SELECT NAME=country[] id="country" onchange="change(this,'city')">
<option value=' ' selected='selected'>Please Choose one</option>
<option value'1'>UK</option>
<option value'2'>USA</option>
<option value'3'>France</option>
</select>

<SELECT NAME=city[] id="city" onchange="change(this,'country')">
<option value=' ' selected='selected'>Please Choose one</option>
<option value'1'>London</option>
<option value'2'>New York</option>
<option value'3'>Paris</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to approach this is to store the table row element in a variable, manipulate its children and then, append it.

Here's the code i wrote. See if it helps. http://jsfiddle.net/drYKX/

Comment: Thanks but how would I change the onchange part as well as the select id will be incrementing?

Comment: If you are arbitrarily changing the id, you can just remove it. It would be easier to keep track of the elements using another thing than just the id (which can be virtually any value if you allow changing it without any kind of limit).

Comment: If I am using anything just for the id, how would I be able to make the select tag linked and the other added row underneath it? I would also need to edit the onchange part as well?